# PEP 8: Function and method arguments naming convention

Tags: python, python-3.x, arguments, naming-conventions, pep8

From PEP 8 section of Function and method arguments :

> Always use self for the first argument to instance methods.
>
> Always use cls for the first argument to class methods.
>
> If a function argument's name clashes with a reserved keyword, it is generally better to append a >single trailing underscore rather than use an abbreviation or spelling corruption. Thus class_ is >better than clss. (Perhaps better is to avoid such clashes by using a synonym.)

It does not say anything about the preferred naming style. I guess it should be "lower_case_with_underscores" or "mixedCase" but I am not sure. What is preferred?

Answer (score 1):

From the PEP 8 section immediately above the one you quoted.

> ### Function Names
>
> Function names should be lowercase, with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve readability.
>
> mixedCase is allowed only in contexts where that's already the prevailing style
> (e.g. threading.py), to retain backwards compatibility.

Link: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-names

Answer (score 0):

For function and method arguments, **lowercase with underscore** is conventional as shown below:

```py
                       # Here
def display_first_name(first_name):
    print(first_name)
```